# Stop jQuery "click scroll" reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mousedown

I have a little script running so i can scroll trough a div with the mousedown option. Unfortunately it resets on each click and i can't  quite figure out why it is doing this.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var clicked = false, clickX;
    $("#gallery").on({
        'mousemove': function(e) {
            clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
        },
        'mousedown': function(e) {
            clicked = true;
            clickX = e.pageX;
        },
        'mouseup': function() {
            clicked = false;
            $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
        }
    });

    var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
        $('#gallery').scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX));
    }
  });
</script>
```

I am assuming it has something to do with

```
clickX = e.pageX;

$('#gallery').scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX));
```

Why am I? because : *"Returns the horizontal coordinate of the event relative to whole document."*
So I am assuming it takes the original position when you click but it doesnt update when you actually scroll this. Anyone has a fix for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fLr4d7kt/6/

Comment: Could you post your html? A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be great.

Comment: the fiddle gives error, but my editor does not? (php storm)

Comment: Okey, it works if you set in on the left to jQuery, now you can see my "reset" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have fixed it like this :

```
$(function () {
    var scroll = 0;

    $(function () {
        var clicked = false, clickX;
        $("#gallery").on({
            'mousemove': function(e) {
                clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
            },
            'mousedown': function(e) {
                clicked = true;
                clickX = e.pageX;
                scroll = $('#gallery').scrollLeft();
            },
            'mouseup': function() {
                clicked = false;
                $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
            }
        });

        var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
            $('#gallery').scrollLeft(scroll + (clickX - e.pageX));
        }
    });
});
```

js: http://jsfiddle.net/fLr4d7kt/10/